Dynamically handle Dropzone maxFiles in edit Mode
I am using dropzone with laravel blade.
In edit mode i want to compare with existing photo count with maxFiles value. Also, check the maxFiles condition dynamically when user upload new images or remove images. Note that user can upload new images and can remove images from both the new and old/existing images also.
Here is my code:
var uploadedDocumentMap = {}
 var existingImagesCount = {{ count($images) }};
 var maxAllowedFiles = 10;
 var totalFilesCount = existingImagesCount;        
Dropzone.options.dpzMultipleFiles = {
        // Your existing options...
        url: '{{ route('frontend.post.media.update') }}',
        maxFilesize: 2, // MB
        maxFiles: maxAllowedFiles - existingImagesCount,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        },
        success: function (file, response) {
           
            $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="images[]" value="' + response.name + '">')
            uploadedDocumentMap[file.name] = response.name;
            totalFilesCount++;
            this.options.maxFiles = maxAllowedFiles - totalFilesCount - existingImagesCount;
            
        },
        removedfile: function (file) {
    
            file.previewElement.remove()
            var name = ''
            if (typeof file.file_name !== 'undefined') {
            name = file.file_name
            } else {
            name = uploadedDocumentMap[file.name]
            }
            
            $('form').find('input[name="images[]"][value="' + name + '"]').remove();
            totalFilesCount--;
            this.options.maxFiles = maxAllowedFiles - totalFilesCount - existingImagesCount;
            
        },
        init: function () {
            var myDropzone = this;
            // Loop through existing images and add them to Dropzone
            @foreach($images as $image)
                var imagePath = "{{ $image }}";
                var filename = imagePath.split('/').pop();
                var mockFile = { name: filename}; // Size can be any arbitrary value
                //var mockFile = { name: "{{ $image }}"}; 
                myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
                myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "{{ asset($image) }}");
                myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
                $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="images[]" value="' + mockFile.name + '">')
                uploadedDocumentMap[mockFile.name] = mockFile.name
            @endforeach
    
        }
    };

Here I want to handle maxFiles dynamically but failed.  maxFiles not working as expected.
For example, if maxAllowedFiles = 10 and i have 6 images in edit mode as existingImages the user will be allowed to upload 4 images. If user delete images then he can upload until total image count not crossing 10.
That means in all cases, there will be 10 file max.
How to do it?
